# Installation of Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am interested in Arch Linux because it seems like it would be a learning experience to install and use it...and because I read that being so minimal it is pretty fast (is this true?)

But I was wondering if anyone has a step-by-step guide of how to do it for complete and total beginners? This is my only computer, so I will be writing down the entire guide for reference while I install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arch Linux **has** a step-by-step guide.

[Arch Linux Beginner's guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide).

First, read the [FAQ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FAQ), then follow the guide.  If you run into any problems talk to the Arch ppl on IRC at irc://irc.freenode.net/#archlinux.

Answer (score 0):

Arch-Linux is in effect a good way to learn some Linux tips. If you find that the installation is too difficult because you don't know basis (some shell, what is a HDD partition..), maybe you are trying to pass a too large step and you should use a Linux before installing one. In this case I think that you should try a LiveCD (of arch-linux if you want).

I can recommend you good installation guide with explicit commands : http://www.themukt.com/2014/06/07/arch-linux-tutorial/

It is an alternative for the official guide, with more details. You will learn how to begin the installation, process it, and install some packages.

Answer (score 0):

Installation and Configuration of Arch Linux step-by-step guide:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Arch-Linux

OR

http://www.tecmint.com/arch-linux-installation-guide/

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link within in your answer. Thanks.